# Cancel an In-App Purchase auto renewable subscription and purchase downgraded subscription iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, in-app

I need to know, If a user cancel an ongoing subscription plan and then purchase a downgraded subscription, will the downgraded subscription be activated just after purchasing it or user has to wait to the end of the previous upgraded subscription cycle?

Cause in normal auto renewable cycle, if user downgrade to a smaller plan, they have to wait till the ongoing upgraded plan comes to an end. And then the new cycle (downgraded) begins.

Comment: Users can't cancel a subscription, they just turn off auto renew, in which case the new subscription tier would start at the end of the current period. They can ask Apple to cancel a subscription if they purchased it in error, but Apple would probably only do this if they ask within a few hours or a day of the purchase.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks. That's what I wanted to know. If Apple cancel a subscription for user's request, and after passing couple of days that same user try to purchase a lower product plan, would this lower plan be activated immediately from that day? Or It will be activated after completing the previous higher plan cycle, just the way it works for downgrade auto renewable cycle?

Comment: It would be activated immediately

Comment: @Paulw11 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71250011/sometimes-receipt-validation-for-in-app-purchase-is-taking-to-much-time-to-give Can you take have a look on it, please?